# RoR - create record on many-to-many join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, join

I have the following models:

```
Client.rb
  has_many :establishments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :establishments

  has_many :addressess, through: :establishments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses


Establishment.rb
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :client


Address.rb
  has_many :establishments
```

On the `show` view of the `Client` I created a `<%= link_to "New Establishment", new_client_address_path(@client)%>` in order to create a new Address record and a new Establishment to the client.

On the `AddressController` I have:

```
     def new
        @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
        @address = @client.addresses.build
      end
```

```
  def create
    @address = Address.new(address_params)

    respond_to do |format|
     if @address.save
      format.html { redirect_to @address, notice: 'Estabelecimento criado com sucesso.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @address }
     else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
    end
   end
```

this will create the new Address but does not create the new Establishment. Can this automatically create the new Establishment that links the `Client` and the `Address`? Before you ask, I really need to have this `Establishment` model.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

In you models:

```
Client.rb
  has_many :establishments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :establishments

  has_many :addresses, through: :establishments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses


Establishment.rb
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :client


Address.rb
  has_many :establishments
  has_many :clients, through: :establishments
```

in your controller:

```
class AddressController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
    @client.establishments.build.build_address
    # if you have a column in establishment, for example: name
    # you can do something like this to set establishment's name:
    # @client.establishments.build(name: 'First connection').build_address
  end

  # create method doesn't need to be changed!!

end
```

in your view:

```
<%= form_for(@client) do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :name %>

  <%= form.fields_for(:establishments) do |establishment_form| %>
    <% establishment = establishment_form.object.name.titleize %>
    <%= establishment_form.input :name, as: :hidden %>
    <%= establishment_form.fields_for(:address) do |address_form| %>
      <%= address_form.input :address1, label: "#{establishment} address1" %>
      <%= address_form.input :address2, label: "#{establishment} address2" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

and you're all set!!

Comment: the view that you refer is for the Address or Client ?

Comment: My bad. You already have client and want establishment and address to be created? Please see the update code. View is address/new.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

First things first - you won't be able to use the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses` call - you can only pass associative data through immediately connected models

I'll explain how to pass the data you want, but first let me explain how to do this correctly:

--

**Collection Data**

If you want to associate two existing objects through a join table, you'll be able to use some of the [`collection` methods in ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), namely [`other_ids`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Collection+associations+%28one-to-many+%2F+many-to-many%29)

```
#app/views/clients/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @client do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :establishment_ids, Establishment.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will populate the `[other]_ids` method in your `Client` model, which will essentially populate the `has_many :through` join model you have.

This will only work if you have `Establishment` records you already wish to associate with your newly created `Client`.

--

**Nested Attributes**

If you want to create a new `Establishment` record, you'll have to send the data to the `Address` model, and *then* to the `Establishment` model:

```
#app/models/client.rb
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :establishments
   has_many :addresses, through: :establishments
end

#app/models/establishment.rb
class Establishment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :client
   belongs_to :address
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

#app/models/address.rb
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :establishments
   has_many :clients, through: :establishments
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
#app/controllers/clients_controller.rb
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
   def new
     @client = Client.new
     @client.establishments.build.build_address
   end

   def create
      @client = Client.new client_params
      @client.save
   end

   private 

   def client_params
      params.require(:client).permit(establishments_attributes: [address_attributes:[]])
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following form:

```
#app/views/cients/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @client do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :establishments do |e| %>
      <%= e.fields_for :address do |a| %>
         ...
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. the form will be at the Address Controller. The client will be sent to the AddressController, which will create a new Address to the Client. The accepts_nested_attributes_for is working with the Client and Address